# golang http client/server based on net.conn

Tags: http, go, tcp

I am wondering if there is easy way to reverse the http client/server tcp connection direction with golang.

I would like http client behavior on tcp listen port, and http server on tcp dial out .

Is there a way init/create http client or server based on already established net.conn and using them?

thanks.

Comment: *http.Request.Write, http.ReadRequest, and http.ReadResponse may be a start. You probably end up re-implementing much of the http package though, like draining and closing request bodies, connection pools, keep-alive and such. It's certainly not easy with just the standard library.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what on earth would you use this for?